# How to implement a neural network in space Invaders?

Tags: unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I am working on a space invaders clone in unity game engine. I want to make the enemies intelligent.
One approach I tried was using a min max algorithm. I took the x-coordinates of player and made the min max tree from it and the used it to make the enemy turn away from that position after specific time intervals. However this did not work well.
Now I want the enemies to learn and evolve to avoid the player using a neural network. How can I implement this in space invaders?
Are there other algorithms better then neural networks to use in space invaders?

Answer (score 2):

Almost any learning algorithm would be better than neural networks.  However it is a very deep topic -- what you need is a book and a few months, not a quick answer on SO.

So I'll recommend a few:

- [Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136042597) by Russell & Norvig.
- [AI Game Programming Wisdom](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1584500778) by Steve Rabin (ed).
- [Artificial Intelligence for Games](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123747317) by Millington & Funge.

I don't recommend neural networks for this because they take a very long time to learn, even with the most modern learning-optimization techniques (which I don't think you're going to find in any book yet anyway).  You want these invaders to learn on the fly, so you need something much more responsive.

I would probably use a decision tree, and keep a limited-length memory vector so that the critters can adapt quickly to changes in the player's strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Neural network is complex mechanism in game AI. But main feature for game AI is to emulate most common features of human behaviour, something like Turing test in game.
Perhaps, it's better to use GOAP and FSM technologies to develop logic faster, but almost with same requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You said it, you want the enemies to "evolve". Yes, I think neural nets are the way to go for this kind of thing. More precisely, evolutionary developed neural nets. But you will need a way to train them... fast. Here's what I would do: first build an AI for shooting the enemies.. something simple enough. Then run an evolutionary algorithm to develop and train the best enemy AI neural nets, while your manually developed player AI tries to kill them. To take this a step further: endow your player AI with an evo neural net as well, and let it learn to kill the enemies as efficiently as possible. Then, let them all evolve together. You will obtain some of the most intelligent enemies ever (and a really good player AI - in case you needed that). You can then choose different individuals from different generations to represent different difficulty levels in your game.